# Modify case equation's brace

Tags: equations, cases

I was wondering if there is a way to change, case's symbol(curly brace) to two arrows pointing up/left and down/left.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}=&0\;\begin{cases}\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \\     \hat{\eta}\times (\mathbf{E_2}-\mathbf{E_1})=0\mbox{(continiuty)}\end{cases}\\
1+1=&2
\end{align}
%TikZ code "illustrating" the new "brace"
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly here is a multiarrowed version:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{arrowcases/.style={matrix anchor=west,%
  nodes={anchor=base west,%
         name=arrc-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn},%
  execute at begin cell=\node\bgroup\math\displaystyle,%
  execute at end cell=\endmath\egroup;,%
  ampersand replacement=\&}}

\def\beginarrowcases#1\endarrowcases{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(O)]
  \matrix [arrowcases] {
  #1
  };
  \coordinate (A) at (arrc-1-1.west);
  \coordinate (B) at (arrc-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1.west);
  \coordinate (start) at ($(A)!0.5!(B) - (1em,0)$);
  \foreach \nn in {1,...,\pgfmatrixcurrentrow} {
    \draw[->] (start) -- (arrc-\nn-1.west);
  };
  \coordinate (O) at ($(start)-(0,0.5ex)$);
  \node at (-1em,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
  \mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}&=0
  \beginarrowcases
    \mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \\
    \hat{\eta}\times (\mathbf{E_2}-\mathbf{E_1})=0 \&
    \text{(continuity)} \\
    \mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \& \text{(again)}\\
  \endarrowcases \\
  1+1 &= 2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This is obtained by making a `matrix of math nodes` like construction in `tikz` to build a cases like setup and then drawing the arrows.  The syntax requires `\&` instead of `&` and `\\` at the end of each line, because of the way the `matrix` construction is set-up in `tikz` and becuase of interaction with the `amsmath` package.

Secondly, here is how one replaces the `cases` bracket with another delimiter directly in the `cases` environment:

[image: Sample cases output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{cases}[1][\lbrace]{%
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases{#1}
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}

\def\env@cases#1{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left#1
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}&=0
  \begin{cases}
    \mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \\
    \hat{\eta}\times (\mathbf{E_2}-\mathbf{E_1})=0
    &\text{(continiuty)}
  \end{cases}
  \\
  1+1&=2\\
  \mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}&=0
  \begin{cases}[\langle]
    \mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \\
    \hat{\eta}\times (\mathbf{E_2}-\mathbf{E_1})=0
    &\text{(continiuty)}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This acheived by redefining the `cases` environment to take an optional argument and putting that in the code at the place where `\lbrace` was hard coded.

Using a `tikz` picture for such a brace in this version is problematic.  For a start one needs a construction that can be resized via `\left`.  Furthermore in your request, you have arrows pointing to each row and that is hard to control.  Hence, the multiarrowed code above is probably more what you want.

Comment: Yes!!!It's working? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Very neat, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A possible way with TikZ:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

%TikZ code "illustrating" the new "brace"
\newcommand{\newbrace}[1][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
\draw[#1] (0,0) -- (0.3,0.3);
\draw[#1] (0,0) -- (0.3,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% the optional argument allows you to select the type of arrow 
% you can also customize the "new brace"
\newenvironment{casesnew}[1][->]%
{\;\newbrace[#1]\;\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}=&\; 0
\begin{casesnew}
\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \\
\hat{\eta}\times (\mathbf{E_2}-\mathbf{E_1})=0 \; \text{(continuity)}
\end{casesnew}\\
1+1=&\;2
\end{align}

Example with customization:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{E}=&\;0
\begin{casesnew}[-stealth,red]
\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi \\
\hat{\eta}\times (\mathbf{E_2}-\mathbf{E_1})=0 \; \text{(continuity)}
\end{casesnew}\\
1+1=&\;2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

#### Disclaimer

The solution works only for two cases.

Comment: There should be more space between the equality operators on the left and the following digits.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: oh, that's right. I'll edit the answer, thanks :)

Comment: The `align` environment was intended to alignwithout user-intervention. You should write: `...\mathbf{E}&=0` not `...\mathbf{E}=&\;0`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Nice!!! Is there a way to do it for more that two cases? Actually to be able to automatically pick the right amount of arrows?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Thank's for the advice! I'll change it to see the difference!